# Set file owner:group in Linux using Qt/C++

Tags: linux, qt, file-ownership, qfileinfo

I need to change the owner and group of a file under Linux using Qt 5.7 /C++.  I found the `QFileInfo::ownerID` and `QFileInfo::groupID` getters, but there appear to be no setters for these values.

I need the Qt equivalent of chown.

Is there a way to set these values using Qt functions?

Comment: try with QProcess

Comment: I was hoping to use a native Qt function, otherwise chown from C/C++ is next best thing.  Using QProcess seems like a lot of overhead and doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: There are no such features in Qt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting file permissions can be done by [QFile::setPermissions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#setPermissions) method instead of using native chmod function, but Qt has not equivalent of chown. You should use `chown()` function from `unistd.h` [Look here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chown.html).

Comment: I wasn't looking for file permissions, just ownership.  But accepted the answer for the second part of the question.